# Jersey with liferay, Servlet to portlet conversion

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, liferay, portlet

I have a webservlet with Jersey rest API configured. Now I have to convert the servlet to a liferay portlet. How to convert? Like what portlet-class should I specify in my portlet.xml? The below is the web.xml of my servlet.

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>charts</servlet-name>
    <!--<servlet-class>javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet</servlet-class>-->
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.charts.api.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>charts</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/charts</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/charts/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

How to configure my portlet.xml and use rest service with my portal? I have to deploy the portlet in liferay jboss server as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a delegate servlet in liferay?

You can create a liferay portlet and in web.xml define your delegate servlet.

Here you've got a definition example:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>buscador</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalDelegateServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>servlet-class</param-name>
        <param-value>com.dummy.servlet.BuscadorServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sub-context</param-name>
        <param-value>buscador</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

It will listens on http://yourliferay/delegate/buscador

Hope it helps